# How to use java 8 streams to make a new list by using another's list objects values with filter?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following things:

```
class AAA {
  String A1;
  String A2;
  String A3;
  String A4;
}

class BBB {
  String A3;
  String A4;
}


List<AAA> aaaList= new ArrayList<>(); // has 10 objects
```

I want to fill up the second list with BBB objects in case A1 and A2 values are equals. So something like this:

```
List<BBB> bbbList = aaaList.stream().filter(obj -> obj.getA1().equals(obj.getA2())).map(obj -> new BBB(obj.getA3(), obj.getA4())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But no idea how exactly this should look like to work...

Comment: You already gave an answer. What is the exact problem?

Comment: Is this correct?? If I have 10 objects in the first list, and there are 5 that should be in the B list, the map() will iterate through only on that 5?

Comment: Yes, because of the filter you used.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad seems more like a confirmation lookup, voting to close as Off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming that the classes have the appropriate getters, setters.
The constructors take the arguments in sequence.

So This:

```
List<AAA> listAAA =
        new ArrayList<>(List.of(new AAA("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                new AAA("1", "1", "30", "40"),
                new AAA("5", "6", "3", "4"),
                new AAA("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                new AAA("4", "4", "50", "60")));
List<BBB> listBBB = listAAA.stream()
        .filter(ob -> ob.getA1().equals(ob.getA2()))
        .map(ob -> new BBB(ob.getA3(), ob.getA4()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(listBBB);
```

Would print this:

```
[BBB [A3=30, A4=40], BBB [A3=50, A4=60]]
```

Comment: How is this different from the code in the question(apart from breaking the same code in different lines and variable renaming)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, with explanation in comments.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

//Note - Object.toString() was defined for AAA & BBB classes. Their member variables are public just to reduce code.
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        //Generate some test data.
        List<AAA> testData = Stream
                .of(1,2,3,4,5)
                .map(i -> new AAA(i+"", (i%3)+"", i*3+"", i*4+""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());//% is modulo operator.

        System.out.println("Test data:\n");
        testData.forEach(System.out::println);

        List<BBB> processedData = testData
                .stream()
                //If a.A1 = a.A2, then allow it.
                .filter(a -> a.A1.equals(a.A2))
                //Take an AAA and convert it into a BBB.
                .map(a -> new BBB(a.A3, a.A4))
                //Collect all the BBBs and put them in a list.
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("Processed data:\n");
        processedData.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Test data:

AAA{A1='1', A2='1', A3='3', A4='4'}
AAA{A1='2', A2='2', A3='6', A4='8'}
AAA{A1='3', A2='0', A3='9', A4='12'}
AAA{A1='4', A2='1', A3='12', A4='16'}
AAA{A1='5', A2='2', A3='15', A4='20'}
Processed data:

BBB{A3='3', A4='4'}
BBB{A3='6', A4='8'}
```